# Common Lisp: relative path to absolute

Tags: common-lisp, pathname

May be it is a really dumb question, but after playing around with all built-in *pathname*-family functions and `cl-fad`/`pathname-utils` packages I still can't figure out how to convert a relative path to absolute (with respect to $PWD):

```
; let PWD be "/very/long/way"
(abspath "../road/home"); -> "/very/long/road/home"
```

Where the hypothetical function `abspath` works just like `os.path.abspath()` in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the final solution (based on the previous two answers):

```
(defun abspath
       (path-string)
   (uiop:unix-namestring
    (uiop:merge-pathnames*
     (uiop:parse-unix-namestring path-string))))
```

`uiop:parse-unix-namestring` converts the string argument to a pathname, replacing `.` and `..` references; `uiop:merge-pathnames*` translates a relative pathname to absolute; `uiop:unix-namestring` converts the pathname back to a string.

Also, if you know for sure what kind of file the path points to, you can use either:

```
(uiop:unix-namestring (uiop:file-exists-p path))
```

or

```
(uiop:unix-namestring (uiop:directory-exists-p path))
```

because both `file-exists-p` and `directory-exists-p` return absolute pathnames (or `nil`, if file does not exist).

**UPDATE:**

Apparently in some implementations (like *ManKai Common Lisp*) `uiop:merge-pathnames*` does not prepend the directory part if the given pathname lacks `./` prefix (for example if you feed it `#P"main.c"` rather than `#P"./main.c"`). So the safer solution is:

```
(defun abspath
       (path-string &optional (dir-name (uiop:getcwd)))
   (uiop:unix-namestring
    (uiop:ensure-absolute-pathname
     (uiop:merge-pathnames*
      (uiop:parse-unix-namestring path-string))
     dir-name)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The variable [`*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_defaul.htm) usually contains your initial working directory, you can merge the pathname with that;

```
(defun abspath (pathname)
  (merge-pathnames pathname *default-pathname-defaults*))
```

And since this is the default for the second argument to `merge-pathnames`, you can simply write:

```
(defun abspath (pathname)
  (merge-pathnames pathname))
```

Comment: Checked. Woks in ECL and SBCL. CLISP is broken (for some reason `*default-pathname-defaults*` is empty there). OK. But how to resolve `..` references - `cl-fad:canonical-pathname` doesn't work?

Comment: Cool idea! I would recommend uiop:merge-pathnames* though.

Answer (score 4):

#### UIOP

Here is what the documentation of [**UIOP**](http://quickdocs.org/uiop/) says about **cl-fad** :-)

> UIOP completely replaces it with better design and implementation

A good number of implementations ship with UIOP (used by ASDF3), so it's basically already available when you need it (see *"Using UIOP"* in the doc.). One of the many functions defined in the library is `uiop:parse-unix-namestring`, which understands the syntax of Unix filenames without checking if the path designates an existing file or directory. However the double-dot is parsed as `:back` or `:up` which is not necessarily supported by your implementation. With SBCL, it is the case and the path is simplified. Note that pathnames allows to use both `:back` and `:up` components; `:back` can be simplified easily by looking at the pathname only (it is a syntactic up directory), whereas `:up` is the semantic up directory, meaning that it depends on the actual file system. You have a better chance to obtain a canonical file name if the file name exists.

#### Truename

You can also call [`TRUENAME`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_tn.htm), which will probably get rid of the ".." components in your path. See also [*20.1.3 Truenames*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/20_ac.htm) which explains that you can point to the same file by using different pathnames, but that there is generally one "canonical" name.

Comment: Nope. `(uiop:parse-unix-namestring "/very/long/way/../road/home")` evals to `#<Unprintable pathname>` (just as any other input). As for `truename` - it does the job, but only when the file **actually exists**, otherwise it signals en error (which is very inconvenient).

Comment: @AlexDarkVoid There seem to be a difference among implementations and/or versions. I have UIOP 3.1.5 here with SBCL which works fine with your example.

Comment: Seems like at least ECL doesn't support `:BACK` in the pathname directory component: `(make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "very" "long" "way" :back "road") :name "home")`.